# Is it possible to demonstrate using the deductive system L the disjunction elimination?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I would like to build a formal proof of the reasoning $(P⇒Q)∧(R⇒Q)∧(P∨R)⊢ Q$ using the following set of axioms:

[image]

Comment: What's $\implies$ here? If it's the standard implication then you should be able to use any standard proof of disjunction elimination (and it will need more axioms than are present here). In system L it's an axiom. Otherwise no proof exists because there's no elimination for $\implies$ here, especially not one including $\vee$

Comment: Since the axioms only involve $\neg$ and $\rightarrow$, you'll need to rewrite the $\land$ and $\lor$ in twrms of $\neg$ and $\rightarrow$ ... are you provided with those definitions?

Comment: Bram28 Yes, but I do not know how to proceed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mendelson's system $P \lor R$ is defined as $(¬P) → R$ (see page 36).

Thus, we have firstly to rewrite the formula without $∨$:

> $(P \to Q),(R \to Q) \vdash ((\lnot P \to R) \to Q)$.

1) $(P \to Q)$ --- premise

2) $(R \to Q)$ --- premise

3) $(\lnot P \to R)$ --- premise

4) $(\lnot Q \to \lnot P)$ --- from 1) by Lemma 1.11(e): $(\mathcal B \to \mathcal C) \to (\lnot \mathcal C \to \lnot \mathcal B)$

5) $(\lnot Q \to R)$ --- from 4) and 3) by Ex.1.47(b): $\mathcal B \to \mathcal C,  \mathcal C \to \mathcal D \vdash \mathcal B \to \mathcal D$

6) $(\lnot Q \to \lnot R)$ --- from 2) by Lemma 1.11(e)

7) $\vdash (\lnot Q \to \lnot R) \to ((\lnot Q \to R) \to Q)$ --- form axiom schema (A3)

8) $Q$ --- from 7), 6) and 5, by *Modus Ponens* twice

> 9) $(P \to Q), (R \to Q) \vdash ((\lnot P \to R) \to Q)$ --- from 1), 2), 3) and 8) by *Deduction Theorm*.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much, I did a similar demonstration too, but I wanted to have feedback from someone.